# Como cargar y visualizar una imagen local

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo puedo mostrar una imagen en un `img` seleccionando el archivo con un `input type file`?

```html
<img id="img1" src="" height="100px" width="100px" border="solid 1px">
    <input id="inputFile1" type="file">

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

        function init() {
            var inputFile = document.querySelector('#inputFile1');
            inputFile.addEventListener('change', mostrarImagen, false);
        }

        function mostrarImagen(e) {
            var img = document.querySelector('#img1');
            var inputFile = document.querySelector('#inputFile1');
            img.src = inputFile.value;
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando la [`API FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) (`IE10+`) de `HTML5`

```js
function init() {
  var inputFile = document.getElementById('inputFile1');
  inputFile.addEventListener('change', mostrarImagen, false);
}

function mostrarImagen(event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    var img = document.getElementById('img1');
    img.src= event.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

window.addEventListener('load', init, false);
```

```html
<img id="img1"><br/>
<input id="inputFile1" type="file">
```